# SQL - Sorting Hierarchical Data (Child -> Parent Relation)

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchical

I'm trying to elegantly show data which is very similar to **file system structure**.

Table Legend:

`Learning Path` - something like folder which can contain `ExerciseSet` or another child `LearningPath`

`ExerciseSet` - something like `file` in file system structure.

`LearningPathItem` - table which is a reference to either a `ExerciseSet` or `LearningPath`. `LearningPath` is composed from `LearningPathItem`s and these are then connected to `ExerciseSet` or `LearningPath` by `itemId` column.

Example structure:

```
Learning Path 1
-> Exercise Set 1
-> Learning Path 2
-> -> Exercise Set 2
-> -> Exercise Set 3
-> -> Learning Path 3
-> -> -> Exercise Set 4
-> -> -> Exercise Set 5
-> Exercise Set 6
```

Here is my CTE SQL Query to recursively traverse through and build a tree based on `child -> parent` relation (`learningPath` column on `LearningPathItem` is a parent here). `LearningPathItem` table can be either a reference to `ExerciseSet`(*file analogy)* or `Learning Path` (*folder analogy*).

```sql
  WITH RECURSIVE tree_view AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        "itemId",
        TYPE,
        "order",
        "learningPath",
        0 AS level
    FROM
        "LearningPathItem"
    WHERE
        "learningPath" = 'cl5y0o4a60273zas89c0yskey'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        child.id,
        child. "itemId",
        child.type,
        child. "order",
        child. "learningPath" AS parent,§
        level + 1 AS level
    FROM
        "LearningPathItem" child
        JOIN tree_view tv ON child. "learningPath" = tv. "itemId"
)
SELECT
    tv.type,
    tv. "itemId",
    lp.title AS "Learning Path Title",
    es.title AS "Exercise Set Title",
    tv. "learningPath" AS parent,
    tv.level,
    tv.order,
    uonlp.efactor AS "Learning Path efactor",
    m.efactor AS "Exercise Set efactor"
FROM
    tree_view tv
    LEFT JOIN "Memoization" m ON m. "exerciseSet" = tv. "itemId"
        AND m. "user" = 'cl524cilt0035d6s8wymsgb4o'
    LEFT JOIN "LearningPath" lp ON lp.id = tv. "itemId"
    LEFT JOIN "ExerciseSet" es ON es.id = tv. "itemId"
    LEFT JOIN "UserOnLearningPath" uonlp ON uonlp. "user" = 'cl524cilt0035d6s8wymsgb4o'
        AND uonlp. "learningPath" = tv. "itemId"
    ORDER BY tv.level, tv.order
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see here I'm simply sorting here by `level` and `order` column, when the perfect and desired order is:

```
Lodash Essentials (set) level 0 order 0
JavaScript Path (path) level 0 order 1
-> JavaScript Essentials (set) level 1 order 0
-> Lodash Essentials 2 (set) level 1 order 1
Root Set (set) level 0 order 2
```

I'm cracking my head on it whole day and can't even figure out if it's even possible here.

Any help here will be great, I can provide more data if needed.

Comment: During the recursion, create an array (`text[]`) to contain the full path from the root to the current row.  Then, sort on the resulting array.

Comment: Two questions: 1) How many direct children (as a maximum) does any parent have? 2) Why the child `-> Exercise Set 1` goes before the child `-> Learning Path 2`?

Comment: One Parent can have one or more Exercise Sets or Learning Paths and there is no limit here. Exercise Set 1 is going before because order of the elements in the list is important. that's why i have `order` column